# How to use the sum of values in an array inside FOR loop Node Js

Tags: javascript

My problem is that I want to get the total sum of SplitValue that has the SplitType of RATIO and use it inside the FOR loop to calculate the ratio of split. i.e. 3 + 2 = 5.
The comments I made in each line of my code below explain my troubles, I'm getting a loop of 3 and 5 instead of just 5. Thanks

```js
var details = {
  "Amount": 1396.8000000000002,
  "SplitInfo": [{
      "SplitType": "RATIO",
      "SplitValue": 3
    },
    {
      "SplitType": "RATIO",
      "SplitValue": 2
    }
  ]
};

var conRatioSumArr = 0;
var balance = details.Amount;

for (var i = 0; i < details.SplitInfo.length; i++) {

  // I want to Get the total sum of SplitValue that has the SplitType of RATIO
  // 3 + 2 = 5
  // Here is what I've tried

  splitTypeArr = details.SplitInfo[i].SplitType;
  splitValueArr = details.SplitInfo[i].SplitValue;

  if (splitTypeArr === "RATIO") {

    conRatioSumArr += splitValueArr;
    console.log(conRatioSumArr); // This gives me a loop of 3 & 5. I only need the total value which is 5 instead of both 3 and 5. Note that if I put this outside the for loop, I get only the total which is 5, but I want to use the sum inside of this for loop not outside the for loop to enable me calculate the ratio below.

    splitAmount = (balance * (splitValueArr / 5)); // The total above is expected to replace the 5 here, but I'm getting a loop of 3 & 5 instead.

    // Like this
    // splitAmount = (balance * (splitValueArr / conRatioSumArr));

    // splitAmount is expected to give: 838.08 and 558.7200000000001 split respectively
    console.log(splitAmount);

  }

}
```

Comment: My understanding is, you simply need to move `splitAmount = ` outside of your for loop. You're already summing the values.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you for your response :). I've tried a lot of things before I posted this, including what you just suggested. The result of splitAmount is expected to be a loop of 838.08 and 558.7200000000001 itself, so moving it outside will return just 558.7200000000001 and not the loop.

Comment: that means i have a bit of a misunderstanding of your goals, i was under the impression the second result was all you expected, ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making it too complicated.

All you need to do is get the total amount of parts in the ratio, and then do the (simple) math.

```js
var details = {
    amount: 1396.8000000000002,
    splitInfo: [
        {
            type: "RATIO",
            value: 3,
        },
        {
            type: "RATIO",
            value: 2,
        },
    ],
};

let totalParts = 0;

for (const split of details.splitInfo) {
    if (split.type == "RATIO") totalParts += split.value;
}

for (const split of details.splitInfo) {
    if (split.type == "RATIO") {
        let amountForSplit = details.amount * (split.value / totalParts);
        console.log(amountForSplit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is simple to understand and modify I hope to your liking. Using the array method `reduce`.

```js
var details = {
  "Amount": 1396.8000000000002,
  "SplitInfo": [{
      "SplitType": "RATIO",
      "SplitValue": 3
    },
    {
      "SplitType": "RATIO",
      "SplitValue": 2
    }
  ]
};

var result = details.SplitInfo.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  if (item.SplitType == "RATIO") {
    agg.sum = (agg.sum || 0) + item.SplitValue
    agg.count = (agg.count || 0) + 1
  }
  return agg;
}, {})

console.log(result)
console.log("average is " + result.sum / result.count)
```

Comment: the result of splitAmount is expected to be a loop of 838.08 and 558.7200000000001 itself, so moving it outside will return just 558.7200000000001 and not the loop.